# Can't exit emergency mode (I do know my root password however)

Tags: boot, password

it all started with my HP Pavilion laptop not being able to connect to the WiFi, since it couldn't find the adapter. So when downloading the following (third party) drivers:

```
sudo apt remove bcmwl-kernel-source && sudo apt install git dkms
git clone -b extended https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

In the terminal I had to set a root password (Which I remember), which I should enter after restarting. But now I am stuck in the emergency mode, with no place to log in..  <kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> doesn't work and I don't know where to log in using my root password.

In the pictures you'll see the output of `cat /etc/fstab` and `sudo blkid`.

Hope one of you will be able to help me out,

Thanks for your time!

[/boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXzPV.jpg)
[ls -al](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paihL.jpg)

[ls -al /lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97i6q.jpg)

[network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VidLe.png)

[remove dkms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVRpX.png)
[network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXKAm.png)

[modinfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecJX7.png)

[ls -al /lib/modules/4.15.0-45 generic/updates/dkms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QaU9.png)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90097/discussion-on-question-by-caughtme-cant-exit-emergency-mode-i-do-know-my-root).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your installation of a dkms driver whilst running kernel 4.15.0-45-generic failed, and caused the computer to no longer boot up. This can be seen by using the `dkms status` command. This may be because you `git cloned` the `-b extended` branch of the code.

Kernel 4.15.0-39-generic still boots, and shows that the wi-fi card IS found, and is using the `iwlwifi` driver.

1. So, whilst booted to -39, lets remove the dkms driver from -45...

In `terminal`...

`sudo dkms remove rtlwifi-new/0.6 -k 4.15.0-45-generic` # remove the dkms driver

`dkms status` # should show nothing, for any kernel

`ls /usr/src` # should not show any rtlwifi* directory

2. At this point, reboot to kernel -45. If it doesn't boot, we'll have to rebuild the `/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-45-generic`. I'll wait with this command for now... didn't need to worry about this.
3. To install the iwlwifi_new driver, do it this way...

In `terminal`... in the -45 kernel...

```
remove the original git cloned folder

git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git

sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new
sudo dkms build rtlwifi-new/0.6
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6

dkms status # should show installed for kernel -45

reboot
```

check wi-fi...

**Update #1:**

delete the git cloned folder

`sudo dkms remove rtlwifi-new/0.6 -k 4.15.0-45-generic`

`sudo rm -r /usr/src/rtlwifi-new-0.6`

Start a new question with title something like "Wi-Fi card not seen on my HP Pavilion laptop". Articulate that you've tried the iwlwifi_new dkms driver and that it didn't work.

Comment: @hernnema worked until ls /usr/src, here I do see the rtlwifi-new-0.6 folder When I ran `sudo dkms remove rtlwifi-new/0.6 -k 4.15.0-45-generic` it did give me at the end: DKMS: uninstall completed.
edit: I am not sure whether the uninstall ran correctly, I edited the question - see last picture
------------------------------
Deleting module version: 0.6
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done. 
Furthermore, dkms status shows nothing indeed

Comment: @Caughtme if it's still there, delete the /usr/src/rtlwifi-new-0.6 folder. Then try and boot -45.

Comment: this command? `rm -R /usr/src/rtlwifi-new-0.6`

Comment: @Caughtme `sudo rm...`

Comment: @hernnema alright done, trying to boot into -45 right now.

Comment: @herynnema you are a hero, a life-saver! booted into -45 without any trouble, via Grub > advanced options. `uname -r` outputs `4.15.0-45-generic`

Comment: @Caughtme now we have to install the new dkms driver... let me edit my answer...

Comment: When I run `git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git` it gives me output: `fatal: destination path 'rtlwifi_new' already exists and is not an empty directory.` I while ls /usr/src doesn't show the directory

Comment: @Caughtme I had just sneaked in a  edit which says to remove the old folder... ;-) Back in 5 mins

Comment: the commands ran without trouble, dkms status show `rtlwifi-new, 0.6, 4.15.0-45-generic, x86_64: installed`
After I rebooted, I tested the wifi. Unfortunately no results. Still the same message "No Wi-Fi adapted found".

Comment: @Caughtme Good job! At least -45 still boots. Lets look at the `sudo lshw -C network` command again. And `lsmod | grep -i iwl`.

Comment: Done, edited my question. Lovely feeling indeed that -45 still boosts

Comment: @Caughtme show me `modinfo iwlwifi|grep -i filename` and `ls -al /lib/modules/4.15.0-45 generic/updates`

Comment: edited my question, you'll find it there in a sec.

Comment: @Caughtme ah! now the directory is there... so show me `ls -al /lib/modules/4.15.0-45 generic/updates/dkms`

Comment: On the edits again :)

Comment: @Caughtme sorry it took so long... I was researching this... since we got -45 booting again, the original question is really solved, and if my answer was helpful, maybe you can mark it as accepted. Then read Update #1, and lets start a new question for the wi-fi problem, which is a different problem, and we'll let someone who has more experience with this specific hardware help you out... 'cause it's not my area of expertise. Make sense?

Comment: Yeah ofcourse! you helped me enormously and I sincerely thank you for all your time. Wish you a nice weekend!

Comment: @Caughtme I'd love to hear from you if/when you finally get wi-fi working!